# Can I publish a DJ mix that uses Creative Commons-licenced music with the No Derivative parameter?

Tags: creative-commons, music

If I record a DJ mix (in which songs are synced, layered and faded in and out) that contains Creative Commons-licensed track with the "No Derivative" parameter (for example, [CC BY-NC-ND 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/)), am I allowed to publish it to download on a website like the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/)? Am I even allowed to publish it for streaming on a website like Mixcloud, like I would with a mix using standard "all rights reserved" music?

My example is [this mix](https://www.mixcloud.com/GNTL/fma-mix-2017/) I built from all CC-licensed tracks taken from the [Free Music Archive](https://freemusicarchive.org/). I assume it is fine to put on Mixcloud as they seem to respect legal imperatives, redistribute royalties and do not allow downloading the recording. But does this mix actually constitute a derivative, and does a CC licence that includes "ND" allow for even less than a standard "all rights reserved" track?

Is it any different to a podcast which includes a CC-ND track (potentially with some fading, and even some talk over) and allows to download it?

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the original in any way, that is a derivative work.